# Two tabs are opened after initialization (chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When the google Chrome instance was initialized , it would always open the Chrome browser with 2 tabs in it with the following strings in the adress bar:
"http://%3D%20c/Users/123/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User%20Data" and "data:,"

The problem is that my programm is randomly selecting one of these pages to work with. How can get rid of one of them and use just one?

Here is my initialization:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir = C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
```

Comment: Closing one of those windows won't help, because it might raise "web view not found" error if the programm had decided to choose the closed window before it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

try with this but I'm not 100% sure that will work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"user-data-dir = C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
```